# why objectValueForTableColumn is called so many times for outlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning outline view of cocoa by Apple OS x developer library. The example source is like this:

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? [FileSystemItem rootItem] : [(FileSystemItem *)item       childAtIndex:index];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? YES : ([item numberOfChildren] != -1);
}

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? 1 : [item numberOfChildren];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    return (item == nil) ? @"/" : [item relativePath];
}
```

This will list all files in my system like a tree.
The question is:
1. if there are 32 files under the "/", the method

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
```

will be called 62 times, I don't know why?
2. the method

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
```

doesn't have a parameter about the row, then how the cocoa to determine which row the item should be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if there are 32 files under the "/", the method

   - (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item

will be called for each row and column as it is displayed. **I assume you have 2 columns and 31 rows are actually shown**.

1. the method doesn't have a parameter about the row, then how the cocoa to determine which row the item should be displayed?

The `item` is a pointer to the object used to populate the table. This is all the `NSOutlineViewDataSource Protocol` needs to know. Details of displayed rows in internal to the `NSOutlineView`